# AudioContext's frequency data differs greatly from OfflineAudioContext's frequency data

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

The title basically explains my problem. I've been comparing the frequency data that is captured using an online and an offline audio context. They seem to differ drastically so I put together this [MWE](https://jsfiddle.net/UNC00KED/ft47Lh5j/) to show the difference.

Basically just upload any audio file and the `OfflineAudioContext` will pick it up immediately and start rendering it. Whenever the rendering has hit 5 the playback second mark for the song, it will output the current frequency data. Once the `OfflineAudioContext` is completely done rendering, you'll see the audio controls on the page get updated and you can play the song. Once the song reaches 5 seconds, using the online `AudioContext`, the frequency data from that analyser will output to the screen.

You'll be able to see that the frequency data between the two, at least for the songs I've been throwing in, varies a lot. Not sure if I'm not understanding the `OfflineAudioContext` fully or what it is, but if anybody has run into something similar or has any ideas on what's going on here, I would appreciate any info you could give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody that runs across this same thing, I finally figured out what the issue was. Whenever I was creating my `OfflineAudioContext`, I was initializing it wrongly. I was doing this

```
let offline = new OfflineAudioContext(2, 44100 * buffer.duration, 44100);
```

when I should've been doing

```
let offline = new OfflineAudioContext(buffer.numberOfChannels, buffer.length, buffer.sampleRate);
```

After I made that change, the frequency data values between the offline context and the realtime one appeared much closer together.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your test file is some kind of music file, then I would expect the results to be different.  Unless you can call `getByteFrequencyData` at exactly the same time, you will get different results because the data in the `AnalyserNode` will be different.  And since `getByteFrequencyData` is called from the main thread and must get data from the audio thread, it's pretty hard to know exactly what data you have.

If you must get the same data for both the offline context and the realtime context, you should use a `ScriptProcessorNode` or `AudioWorkletNode` to guarantee that you get the frequency data at the same time.  (But be consistent; use `ScriptProcessorNode` or `AudioWorkletNode` for both contexts.)

Comment: I decided to put your theory to the test. I generated a single 440hz tone in Audacity that lasted for 30 seconds and ran it through. And I'm still getting different results between the offline context and the realtime context. Here's the MP3 download link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SWaXPdrQPMvRoKiQeGXMYKefmkJc1Qrf/view

Comment: Don't know if Audacity can do this, but perhaps use Matlab or Octave to take the FFT of the sine wave at different points in the wave.  The FFT results will change depending on when you take the FFT.